# Finding polynomials $p(-1)$

Tags: polynomials

When the third-order polynomial $p(x)$ is divided by $x-1$, $x-2$, and $x-3$, the remainders were all $1$ . If the constant term of $p(x)$ is $2$, what is the value of $p(-1)$?

Comment: The polynomial is given by $p(x)=\lambda\cdot (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+1$, where $\lambda$ is such that $p(0)=2$. This fixes $p$ and you can proceed to find $p(-1)$.

Comment: @Caroline That's a good answer. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Artur: To me, an answer should be more worked out. I believe the OP will see this more like a hint. But thank you!

Comment: @Caroline To me, an answer post could very well be brief, or just a hint (I personally wouldn't call what you have there a hint; it's too substantial for that). Comments are not for answers. As the comment box itself says before you type anything in it: Aviod answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ 
$$p(0)=2=d$$
$$p(1)=1$$
$$p(2)=1$$
$$p(3)=1$$
Then $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b+c+2=1 \\ 
8a+4b+2c+2=1 \\ 
27a+9b+3c+2=1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Which gives us
$$a=-\frac{1}{6}$$ $$b=1$$ $$c=-\frac{11}{6}$$
And
$$p(-1)=-1*(-\frac{1}{6})^3+1*1^2+1*(-\frac{11}{6})+2=5$$